# Requesting a new topic should present user with dismissed topics if any

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When requesting a new topic in a dashboard/tag the dialogue tells me

- if a topic with that name already exists
- if a topic with that name is already requested

However, it does not show any dismissed topics. I have dismissed the topics "Design Patterns in PHP" (a global Design Pattern tag already exists) and "MVC in PHP" (too broad) at least three times now. Yet, they keep getting requested.

In order to prevent having to dismiss the same topics over and over again, can we please show dismissed topics with reasons and comments when requesting new topics?

Comment: *Please please please!*

Comment: Don't ignore existing active ones either. Have seen duplicates get  approved with content in both ... right down to exact same topic name. Might have come that way out of private beta ... not sure