# Is it actually intended that Documentation's contents morph in their form?

Tags: discussion, documentation

What I'm actually percieving about documentation is, that the biggest problem is, any one has his own mindset about how the perfect description of an topic should be looking like.

As far as I have noticed (And especially this is the reason for my quiting of documentation) the problem is the content changes very often in big amounts, leaving the docs itself rarely in its form. The latest changes about reviewing are a good step, but I can't see how they will stop this, as also highrep user have diferent ideas about "best practice" and I have seen whole good(!) examples beeing put to scratch, just because some one mentioned that he prefers a specific practice (even presenting reasons for why and making clear it is not required to go this way), and the reviwers didn't like it. And those reviwers often had been >=10k anyway, so this wouldn't be changed. And while the quality may increase, the consistens of the docs remains unstable.

But as this problem has not been addressed at all in the [latest documentation update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331663/2003898) I'm curious about is it even intended to create consistent content in the long run? Or was my assumption wrong from the beginning?

Comment: Until we have talk pages where editors can discuss what the docs should be, yes, you can expect major edits and edit wars as each new user tries to impose their vision of what Docs should be.  I can't tell if this is intentional or not, given that Q&A was expressly designed to discourage discussion.