# My changes to JavaScript documentation goes through review even though I have silver JavaScript tag badge

Tags: bug, documentation

According to [the post about Documentation Update on August 4th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th), I should be able to skip review when submitting changes to JavaScript documentation, as I have a silver JavaScript tag badge.

However, I proposed a [change to the Map topic in JavaScript documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/78872) and its status is "awaiting approval".

After that I made [another change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/78865) and it got auto-approved. Maybe the changes go through review when the change is deleting some examples?

Comment: My feeling is that if a topic has multiple tags you need silver in all of them.

Comment: @JohanLundberg err.. a topic can only belong to a tag, and this doesn't involve examples movement...

Comment: [Same problem as James Donnelly reported a while back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331712/366904). Still no solution.