# When a Documentation edit is auto-approved, don't include an empty "by" label

Tags: feature-request, documentation

One of the [recent changes to Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th) allows trusted users to make changes that take effect instantly, skipping review. This feature warms the cockles of my tiny heart.

However, I have one <strike>excessively trivial feature request</strike> minor nitpick. The approval box for a trusted user's edit currently shows:

> [image: "Approved by " (Trusted to make this change without review.)]

It looks incomplete, like it's missing something. (Because it is.)

It would be much clearer without the extraneous "by". The informational text underneath already adequately explains why there is no reviewer.

> [image: "Approved" (Trusted to make this change without review.)]

Conceptually, this is trivial. But I'm not sure what the behind-the-scenes code looks like that generates this text and how difficult it would be to actually implement this change. If possible, I think it would substantially improve the fit-and-polish that we have grown accustomed to 'round these here parts.

Comment: How about if it would say *Approved by Community*? Assuming behind the scenes the Community user takes the honor for *approving* it, much like dupe -votes and edit rejections

Comment: Well, "Approved by Community" would be OK, but the only real justification for that would be either (1) easier to implement, (2) more technically precise. And that is "technically precise" in the most unimportant of ways. Yes, technically, the Community user has ♦ mod powers, so it needs to approve the edit. But that is just a leaky abstraction. It doesn't actually matter that Community was the one who approved it; the approval was just a technical formality. Because we inherently trust the user making the edit, there was practically no approval. Which is what my wording implies. (cc @rene)

Comment: I kinda agree, it should be without *by* word. I think it's better than adding an additional word *Community*.

Answer (score 21):

If you ask me and as @CodeGray mentioned already, *Approved (by)* or *Approved by Community* is technically wrong, since an auto-approved edit isn’t actually approved by anyone – though **it was revised by the editor** .

So how about something like:

> [image]