# Errors expected in documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

In documentation, it is not acceptable to have wrong information, and when a user suggests an example or an edit to a specific post, there is no guarantee that his suggestions are true even programmatically. As the reviewer also is a regular user without any restrictions, there is not a guarantee that this user will know that the suggestions have mistakes and hence he/she can approve mistakes unknowingly.

So, why aren't there some restrictions about the user who can review and accept these suggestions, like having a badge in the corresponding topic, or having a high enough reputation to review these posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing). Documentation edits require 4 approval or rejection votes by users with at least 100 reputation before they go live or are removed, respectively.

There are also [some increased powers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331663/2756409) given to users who are shown to be subject-matter experts:

> - Users with a silver or gold tag badge (from Q&A) will skip review
>     when they make an edit to that tag's documentation
>
>   - This include aliases, so a sql-server-2008-r2 silver badge will work on sql-server's documentation
>   - If multiple tags are involved (because of moving examples, or submitting multiple topic changes as one) you must have a badge in
>       each tag to skip review
>
>     - Users with a silver or gold tag badge can one-click approve or reject a proposed change from another user to that tag's
>         documentation
>     - Reviews now take 4 "votes" to approve or reject, and how many votes a users approval or rejection counts for is based on their
>         reputation
>   - users with >= 10,000 rep get 3 votes
>   - users with >= 1,000 rep get 2 votes
>   - users with >= 100 rep get 1 vote