# Include Libraries in Documentation examples

Tags: discussion, documentation

So what I am talking about is examples like the ones here: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/784/tpl-dataflow#t=20160810142546707843)

In this case they are using methods and such from `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` and `System.Threading.Tasks` But there is nothing in the example itself that says these are the libraries you need to have to run the examples. If you are new to the language you are then forced to google to figure out what libraries to use.

So should we edit examples to include information like this? And if so, is it better to do it by just adding a using/include/ect at the top or would it be more clear to just put the full namespace in the code like `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock<int>(...);`

Comment: You can just edit the Remarks to include that information. That's what the section is for.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Seems a bit off to force people to scroll to the bottom of the page to find out that kind of information.

Comment: Well, that's a problem with the page layout, not with the definition of the section. [The Documentation developers are talking about adding a section that will be at the top](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th?cb=1), but I don't know when that will be complete.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah ok. That sounds good then.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Though as I tried to do this, I noticed that it is a pain. Different examples use different libraries. Also If a new example is added using libraries different from the others, then remarks would then need to be edited as well.

Comment: It's been my experience that there are many places where doing things in Documentation is "a pain" :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't mean the act of doing it initially, I mean it like  having to rely on people to keep an accurate list in the remarks and keep that list updated when new examples are added, would be a pain for all of us.

Comment: Well, that's part of the challenge with Documentation as a whole. It demands a level of attention that a lot of people are not used to providing. Q&A doesn't demand that (witness the thousands of answered duplicates).