# Unable to approve change to documentation, whole topic, concurrent changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

There are two concurrent (don't know whether it's relevant) changes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/661/pattern-matching#t=201608101935587442677) page:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/77179
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/77746

I deem that they are both worthy but after cliking on the `Approve` button message appears:

[image: One edit]
[image: Second edit]

Tried this multiple times and still I'm not able to make that work.

To anybody thinking that this is a duplicate:

1. The edits are non-empty
2. Both of them have good quality so I must assume many people might have tried aproving them.

Answer (score 1):

We're experimenting with implementing [a hard limit for the number of examples in a topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th?cb=1), with the initial limit set to 12.

There are currently 12 examples in that topic. So previously proposed changes will fail upon approval.

Not sure exactly how to handle these yet, but... A 500-error is clearly not the way to go. The limits are off until we've had time to figure out how this scenario *should* work.

Comment: 500 with helpful comment?