# Earned 700 reputation because I added 2 sentences. Why?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, reputation

I have earned 700 reputation for [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/42113). I added "Async and await can make working with promises easier. Unfortunately, this feature is ES7+." I got 6.69 reputation per character. Is this a bug? Am I really supposed to get 700 reputation for 2 sentences? I think I should have gotten between 5 and 10 reputation. If this is not a bug, I think the maximum reputation for an edit under 200 characters should be 50.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's working as designed. Rest-assured the designers are aware of the reputation imbalances. When changes are made to the algorithm, there will be rep-recalculations.

Comment: Check out their latest [Documentation Update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th?cb=1) where they say that this is something they're working on. You're right it is redonkulous and there's been countless threads about it. So many I'm having difficulty picking a good duplicate.

Comment: It's not a bug. The designer wanted to have it that way. And why not? Your two lines obviously will help thousands of readers in the future.