# Maximum number of examples (6) exceeded?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-examples

I was just trying to contribute something to Documentation, but I got an error saying:

> Maximum number of examples (6) exceeded. Consider deleting examples, moving examples to another topic, or starting (and linking to) a new topic.

[image: Screeshot]

What does this error mean?

Comment: You can only provide up to 6 examples. If you need more, split the topic

Comment: Not sure exactly what do you mean by example??

Comment: @AaghazHussain the individual sections under "Examples" are examples; it looks like the topic you are editing [*currently* has 3](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/360/introduction-to-r) - did you add another 4?

Comment: @MarcGravell Any reason to have limit??

Comment: @MarcGravell only 2

Comment: @AaghazHussain Users with more reputation can add more examples, but the limit is in place to avoid it being a data dump of examples for a single topic.

Comment: Uh... I saw a bunch of topics with WAY more than 6 examples and i still could add more..

Comment: To expand on what @TylerH says: it becomes 12 at 2k rep - they're right about the reasoning, though - it seems preferable to split topics before they become too large

Comment: Take this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/compatibility-between-python-3-and-python-2#t=201608121556471911303

Comment: @Qlstudio I expect that has been "grandfathered in" from the early beta, and is an example of **why** we need those limites

Comment: Oh. Ohkay.... I guess this is only true for new topics?

Comment: Could've sworn I rejected or commented on that edit earlier. "Basic X" is a bad topic, especially under "Intro to Y". Everyone has a different idea of what is basic and this can easily balloon out of proportion. Anyway, we've been talking about organizing the R docs in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: This rule negatively affects even the ability to _edit_ existing examples. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/511/stdvector - I've tried taking edit requests and amending existing articles, and the same error pops up.

Answer (score 5):

There are only three levels of hierarchy in Documentation right now:

1. **Tags** are pretty straightforward; they correspond roughly to tags in Q&A (although not all Q&A tags make for good Documentation tags, and multiple Q&A tags can *alias* to a single Documentation tag).
2. **Topics** are less well-defined. [The help center notes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-anatomy) that a good topic will usually be more broad than a *question*, but until now there's been no upper-limit on that breadth - so you can easily find [topics that could fill a book](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1640/performance-tips).
3. **Examples** are [intended to be self-contained and *succinct*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-examples), each demonstrating some portion of the topic.

Over the past couple weeks, several problems have become apparent:

- **Topics tend to start off *very* broad...** This is actually fine; when Kevin was shopping around the early idea of Documentation, he described the concept as, "a place for stuff that would be closed as Too Broad on Q&A". This thing is supposed to be able to handle "meatier" topics than can be covered in a single question and answer set. However...
- **...and examples just keep expanding to fill that breadth.** It's easy to create a topic that seems reasonably-scoped - say, [exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/40/exception-handling) - and then come back a couple weeks later to find that it's grown up into a tentacled beast with duplicate examples, examples that themselves contain multiple, self-contained examples, arbitrary examples of exceptions from various APIs... The once-reasonable topic is in danger of becoming an unwieldy mess of increasingly long and tangential examples. Especially when...
- **...There's little motivation to create more specific topics if you can cram your example into a broad one.**

Now again, there's nothing *wrong* with having some very broad, high-level topics... But if that's *all* we have then this is going to be impossibly unwieldy in a very short time.

So the goal here is to gently encourage folks to break up topics *as they grow*. The current limits (6 examples for new users, 12 for folks with full editing rights in Q&A) are... Pretty arbitrary; they *sound* reasonable, but chances are we'll have to adjust them at some point.

For now, if you encounter one of these errors... Try to step back and consider the guidance given in the message: if you can break out tangential examples into a more focused topic, do it! If you can *improve* existing examples instead of duplicating them (while keeping them succinct and focused!), then do that instead. If neither is appropriate, report it here on meta so we can reconsider the limits.

Comment: If you want your instruction to be helpful, instead of providing generic hints about thinking and complaining, you should explain what exactly should be done with every single huge topic in Documentation. Nothing was done to address their existence, they were just silently grandfathered, even though there're tons of them and they're the most active.

Comment: They'll need to be broken up, @Squidward. I've said this before, said as much again here, and strongly hint at it in both of the messages displayed by the system. Also, I'm gonna just start deleting comments when folks feel the need to leave two of them back-to-back; I read your answer below, you don't need to paraphrase it badly in a comment on mine.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to split up a Topic "Operators" or "String Functions" (for a given language).

The alternative is to lump all the examples into one "Example"?

Or artificially split the dozens of examples into no more than 6 "Examples"?

Answer (score -3):

Somebody at Stack Overflow decided that in order to make topics less scary, distribute votes evenly or for some other reasons which were never explained, it's great to have [caps on the number of examples per topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th):

- low rep peasants can add 6 examples;
- high rep master race can add 12 examples.

Now, instead of having a single "Java Pitfalls" topic, we now have:

- Java Pitfalls
- Java Pitfalls - Exceptions
- Java Pitfalls - Syntax
- Java Pitfalls - Some Other Stuff

which are completely unrelated, not cross-linked, so it's close to impossible to find them all.

So, the question remains: what to do? Well, you can either earn 2000 reputation, or, as those who had the brilliant idea of example caps suggest, just create more topics:

- Introduction to R - Part 1
- Introduction to R - Part 2
- Introduction to R - Part 3
- Introduction to R - Part 4

This is what we're supposed to do now, aren't we?

Don't you just love how powerful and flexible Documentation becomes over time?

Comment: This answer is borderline rude. The appropriate thing to do is to just keep your Documentation cleaner and simpler rather than trying to make a ten-part series. "Introduction to R" and "Java Pitfalls" both sound like 100% inappropriate topics for Documentation.

Comment: @TylerH You're too kind ...

Comment: @TylerH Limits, rewards and other aspects of the website are designed to tell users what they're expected to do or not to do. If my interpretation of the introduced limit is incorrect, either I'm stupid, or the limit isn't well-designed, or both. I bet both. /  You can make a post about what's appropriate and what's inappropriate for Documentation. Good luck explaining why introductory topics which exist in every single tag are somehow inappropriate for Documentation. I'm dying to hear your explanation.

Comment: @Squidward the Stack Overflow staff have already made several posts about what's appropriate for Documentation. The issue with this post is that it's a passive-aggressive rant, that just so happens to give bad advice, as well. Docs are intended to fill in the missing part of existing specs (namely, useful examples). Docs is **not** the place for programming tutorials.

Comment: @TylerH I beg to disagree — this answer isn't "passive-aggressive", it's full of blatant aggressive sarcasm which debases every single thing mentioned. If somebody has issues understanding that and follows my "bad advice", it isn't my problem. / Introductions tend to contain examples, so de jure, it isn't offtopic. As to the "filling in the missing part" plan, it miserably failed. 90% of "Documentation" exists elsewhere, usually in much higher quality.

Comment: @Squidward It *is* your problem because you're passing it off as a genuine answer.

Comment: @TylerH It's only genuine if you don't bother reading and understanding it. Why can't people these days tell sarcasm apart if it isn't in red letters and decorated with `<sacrasm>` tags?

Comment: @Squidward None of us are mind readers. We can't tell if you meant something sarcastically or not... it's best to assume that if you post an answer on the site, people will interpret it as if you were serious, because an answer is a "formal response". Why bother making a formal response if it's just a sarcastic diss? Leave it as a comment, or better yet, leave it unsaid.

Comment: @TylerH OK, for those who have trouble interpreting my text: 1. This example limit is pointless, artificial, ineffective and makes situation even worse. 2. You can't do anything about it. 3. There're workarounds which make posting content possible, but finding content harder.

Comment: @TylerH "Introduction to R" comes bundled in with Docs for the tag, just like for any tag, and cannot be deleted, inappropriate or not. It's the one where the versions reside.

Comment: @TylerH. I'm still trying to understand the scope of Documentation (even at this late date). You say Docs extend the user's manual with examples, but Docs aren't tutorials. Can you take some time to expand on those thoughts -- maybe even post a new meta question. In particular where does the manual stop and a tutorial begin? Thanks!