# Too many redirects occurred trying to open 31 more examples in the documentation of Bash

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I get the following error on Safari (*Version 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)*) (and something similar on Google Chrome(*Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)*)):

> Too many redirects occurred trying to open “‎stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/4797/internal-variables/16885/%24%23+”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page.

#### How to reproduce?

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics.
2. Click **31 more examples** in the **Internal variables** section.
3. Here it is.

All the other **[:digit:+] more examples** links seem to work fine.

Comment: I didn't think you could even have that many examples... Was it [not supposed to be 6](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332299/maximum-number-of-examples-6-exceeded) ([also here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332360/reducing-the-number-of-examples-in-huge-topics-to-currently-recommended-6-12-e))?

Comment: I can reproduce that. Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 on Linux.

Comment: @Tunaki The examples were created before that limit was added.

Comment: Weirdly, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/4797/internal-variables works

Comment: The issue is the `$# ` title of that example … it just happens that the third example is the $# example and thus being the link for the "31 more examples"… Note that this example has a trailing whitespace in it's title … perhaps this causes the redirect loop?

Comment: Confirmed on latest Opera

Comment: It redirects back to itself. (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/4797/internal-variables/16885/%24%23+ → http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/4797/internal-variables/16885/%24%23+)

Comment: Reproducable with Mozilla Firefox 48.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: And Firefox 48.0.2 on Windows as well.

Comment: Reproducible on Chrome 53.0.2784.46 beta (64-bit) in Xubuntu 16.04.  I'm agreeing with @bwoebi in that it has to do with the escaped `$#` causing some weirdness.

Comment: @bwoebi good catch! I just edited [that example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/revisions/4797?exampleId=16885) and now the issue is gone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @fedorqui just verified, the issue is related to a trailing space in an example title.

Trailing spaces in example titles should thus be trimmed away when submitting to avoid this issue. There is no reason why they should be there at all as browsers render them away when displaying.

Comment: Shouldn't we notify the SE dev team about this issue as well?

Comment: They are supposed to track the bugs tag and should find it themselves

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Your bug report is all the notification we need. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yep, as y'all have figured out by now, the trailing space is the problem here. *In theory*, this should still work as decoding should produce the same title as what we have stored. Unfortunately, `%24%23+` comes through to an ASP.NET route as `$#+`, which of course isn't equal to the properly decoded title `$#<space>`... and then we try to fix the URL and redirect correctly... which lands us in the infinite loop.

I pushed a fix for URLs of existing topics and examples, as well as a change to trim titles for new topics and examples going forward. With you in the next SO build (rev 2016.8.29.3935).