# Proposed change review should link competing proposals

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation, documentation-proposals, proposed-changes

I'm sure that I'm not the only one who has had a [proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/82372?draftId=68920) clobbered by [another change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/83617). Currently proposed changes do not cite if 'accepting' them would clobber other proposed changes. Would it be possible to alert the user when any proposed change has competing proposals, so reviewers know what they are implicitly 'Rejecting' if they 'Approve' a given change? An alert box with links to the competing changes, or something along those lines.

I would assume such a feature would still be useful when the review queue is implemented.

Comment: What do you mean by "flag" here? The system detects a conflict and shows the user a warning/caution banner?

Comment: @TylerH Yes; that is probably a bad use of 'flag', given it's other semantic meaning on stack overflow. I'll update.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's something that's planned in the review queue updates. Not certain if it will make it into v1 or a consecutive update: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th?cb=1

Comment: @KurtisBeavers then add [meta-tag:status-planned]

Comment: Might also be an idea to alert someone before they start making a change that one already exists and is awaiting review.  e.g. I didn't notice someone else had a pending change on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/biztalk?tab=proposedchanges&topicId=5197