# Examples limit on documentation causes examples to be smushed together

Tags: discussion, documentation

This post is 4 examples in one - and they seem unrelated. It all comes under the topic banner, but there is no good reason for them to be together.

[image]

So I edit 3 out, and go to add a new example but this happens:

[image]

Now I know *why* this example is 4 smushed together. There's a cap. I can't see any way this topic could be sensibly split - it's the "Changes between Python 2 and Python 3" topic, so this limit is really making it *harder* to browse.

---

What can be done about this?

Comment: Related, I guess: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332363/

Answer (score 34):

> What can be done about this?

Simple: get rid of such "list of stuff" topics altogether. They tend to be [problematic for reasons discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332369/the-forms-and-quality-of-documentation-topics). Google can find the changes from Python 2 to 3 just fine on its own, so we're just duplicating stuff that has been adequately documented. Such topics make a mockery of the example voting system, and they cause topics to be needlessly huge.

We don't allow list questions; why should we allow list documentation?

Comment: I agree Google will find material buried inside examples. And duplicating adequately documented material is ... needlessly duplicative -- unless SO.Docs wants to become the authoritative source (hmmmm?!). Those issues aside, what is to be done with *useful* miscellany -- good stuff that doesn't easily fit inside a narrow Topic container? Should we increase the Example limit? Should we create multiple Topics include the broad material? Should we elevate each miscellaneous material into a Topic of their own? I don't have an answer. Any ideas?

Comment: @markE: "*good stuff that doesn't easily fit inside a narrow Topic container?*" I don't believe anything of that sort exists. Can you provide an example of something that qualifies as "good stuff" for which you could not create an appropriate topic?

Comment: Sure. :-) See [Drawing common complex shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5133/drawing-common-complex-shapes). This Topic contains some of the many shapes that users may need when creating Charts, Diagrams, Image Annotations, Game controls, etc. The shapes are not exclusive. Any shape might be used when creating multiple apps. And there are many more "everyday" shapes that we might add if allowed the space. Originally we thought to make each type of shape an Example (for easy searching). Any suggestions now that the Example limit applies?

Comment: @markE: Each of those is a *separate* task. Someone who wants to know how to draw arrowheads doesn't necessarily care about drawing stars. Someone interesting in drawing stars doesn't necessarily care about drawing a pie chart. And so forth. Those things out to be separate topics. There needs to be a distinction between "topic as categorization" and "topic as thing to do". The former is a misuse of topics. The only reason we do it is that it's the *only form* of categorization we have.

Comment: Granted, stars & pie-chart are an unlikely pairing. But many of these elements are daily used in combination. Frankly, I stopped adding elements to this Topic when the Example limit was imposed, but there are many other common shapes that could be categorized under this (too broad?) Topic. So if the Topic is being misused (too broad) and yet if it's the only form of categorization we have, how should I proceed: 1. Elevate each shape to a Topic with 1 or 2 examples, 2. Continue to group shapes in larger, general Topics. 3. Something else?

Comment: @markE: I don't really see how having a bunch of random diagrams under one heading is helpful to *anyone*. Do you really expect people to sift through 20 examples of stuff they don't want just to find the one example that they might be interested in?

Comment: Well, yes -- that's what I thought when I set up the Topic! I think it's marginally better to sift through one Topic with 20 related shapes and pick the 3-4 that you need rather than to search for the 3-4 shapes individually. BTW, I'm not pushing an agenda here...I honestly want to know how to handle the question of "Example limit inspires all-in-one smushed Examples". I really need some guidance that I haven't found yet. :-)

Comment: @markE: "*I think it's marginally better to sift through one Topic with 20 related shapes and pick the 3-4 that you need rather than to search for the 3-4 shapes individually.*" Examples have titles, and even the Godawful search system in Docs.SO can search based on those. If someone needs to draw a pie chart, they'll find the example for it no matter what its topic is. The question is, do we want a big topic of random drawing stuff, or do we want to put "draw a pie chart" inside a task that's about... drawing pie charts. There's more than one way to draw a pie chart, after all.

Comment: Ok, I'm feeling a little edgy about tone -- I just really need some direction! :-) I'm certainly **not** proposing a Topic  of "random drawing stuff", I'm proposing a group of elements that are commonly used together in various combinations on a daily basis. So how would you answer the question? How do you suggest I handle **related** non-homogenous elements. Given that there will be >13 of such elements, would I: 1. create >13 topics, 2. "Smush" the elements into 1+ Examples, 3. create a Topic for each of Charts, Diagrams, etc & duplicate the elements into each Topic  4. Something else?

Comment: @markE: "*How do you suggest I handle **related** non-homogenous elements.*" It all depends on how you define "related". I disagree that the topic you showed had elements that were "related" by anything *meaningful*. The only relationship was that they all involve drawing stuff. And that's not the kind of relationship that the current Docs.SO system effectively handles. Even without the example limit, I would argue that Docs.SO works better with focused topics. The kind of relationship is not entirely unimportant, but Docs.SO has no mechanism to support it.

Comment: @markE: Think about it this way: what would you do in Stack Overflow if tags didn't exist? Well, you'd still answer questions as you always did. It would simply be harder to find questions that have similar aspects.

Comment: OK, that helps. :-) I hear you saying that a broad Topic with many loosely related Examples is, on it's face, no good -- specificity must take precedence over loose categorical grouping. I hear Topics are very narrowly focused and Examples must be very highly correlated to the Topic. I'll begin breaking up the Topic. Maybe some of the drawings can be combined into a single Topic. For example: Topic=*Drawing connectors using lines and curves with arrowheads*, Topic=*Drawing regular & rounded polygons*, Topic=*Simple Pie Chart*, Topic=*Simple Donut Chart*.

Comment: @markE: "*Topic=\*Simple Pie Chart\*, Topic=\*Simple Donut Chart\**" Why only "simple"? Why should the topic forbid more complex examples? You seem to be thinking too much in terms of "how to find a place for the code on the site" and less in terms of "what are good tasks that users want to do?"

Comment: Sure, I whole-heartedly agree! I know Topics can contain complex examples. Some Topics I've written are very complex -- combining both mathematical and coding complexities. If there's a "Simple Pie Chart" Topic, there may very well be another [more complex] "Pie Chart" Topic. I say *Simple* to entice beginning coders to this Topic because beginning coders might be confused or overwhelmed by the complexities of [more complex] "Pie Chart". Simple relates to the Topic's targeted audience: inviting a beginning coder to see simple code. Pro's can view [more complex] "Pie Chart". **Good/NoGood?**

Comment: @markE: "*Simple relates to the Topic's targeted audience: inviting a beginning coder to see simple code.*" Topics should not be based on the experience level of the person reading them.

Comment: I don't agree that all Topics should be audience agnostic. Why not two Topics: a friendly introductory Topic for beginners  and a complex Topic for pros?

Comment: @markE: For the same reason we don't have two Stack Overflows. For the same reason we don't have a "beginner" tag for "beginner" questions.

Comment: Is this "one size fits all" an official position? If yes, I'd like to start a discussion about it. SO Q&A has **both beginners and pros** asking questions in any one Tag. If I see a beginner asking a question I answer more simply with more clear steps. Questions from pros get more advanced & concise answers. Answering a beginner with pro style answers often gets "I don't understand, can you explain more simply" from the beginner (or worse, the beginner will go away without understanding).

Comment: @markE: You can answer questions however you like. But you're talking about documentation. That's a community issue. The last thing Docs.SO needs are a bunch of "beginner" topics.

Comment: *"The last thing Docs.SO needs are a bunch of beginner" topics*. Not a "bunch" but Docs.SO does need *some* beginner Topics. We're coders here, and some searchers will be beginners who need beginner code. Failing to have *some* beginner code would be IMHO a failure of Docs.SO.

Comment: @markE actually it doesn't need them, because most "beginner" stuff already exists. Focus on documentation that we don't have anywhere, instead of documentation we ought to have.

Comment: @Braiam. I'm just not with you on your comment ... If uniqueness is a prime Docs consideration, then I think we're failing. As I look at the JavaScript Docs, **I see good material.** I see good material that spans from nice beginner material (that is certainly already available elsewhere) to some nice advanced material (that is likely uniquely available here). Are you suggesting we cull the beginner material? Is uniqueness really a primary criteria for Docs?

Comment: @markE: "Is uniqueness really a primary criteria for Docs?" "[If a project already has awesome documentation that's easy to search and cite, then there's no need to duplicate it on Stack Overflow. We're interested in fixing what's broken with documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213)" That sounds like a "yes" to me. "*I think we're failing*" Throw it on the pile of other things Docs.SO fails with.

Comment: @NicolBolas. So would your ideal Docs === "Unique Advanced Topics" with a prominent entry sign that reads "Not safe for Beginners". **Important question (to me)...!!** Is your view of Documentation held by the Powers-that-Be. It's fine if your views are "official". I just remain confused about what I should be submitting to Documentation. I put a fair amount of effort into my posts and I dread that what I submit is off-topic for Documentation. Please respond!!!!!

Comment: @markE: "*So would your ideal Docs === "Unique Advanced Topics"*" ... where are you getting this "advanced topics" stuff from? My point is that there shouldn't be beginner *or* advanced topics. Topics should be based on what you want to do, not how you want to communicate with people. There's no such thing as an "advanced" way to do a find/replace in a string. There's no such thing as a "beginner" way to search through a filesystem. Topics do not need to have a skill level on them. Specific examples might be easier for some than others, but the topic itself is what it is.

Comment: @markE: "*I just remain confused about what I should be submitting to Documentation.*" Everyone is. Nobody knows what it should be, least of all the Powers That Be. They've decided to take a "wait and see" approach to deciding how Docs.SO should work. I'm merely trying to catalogue the only effective way where Docs.SO as it is currently designed can achieve the goals that they claim to want.

Comment: @markE docs wasn't meant for one, many or any skill level, docs was meant to fill the void of not having practical examples in the existing documentation. That's how it was sold at the beginning.

Comment: @NicolBolas. Ok, I'll give you an example of a beginner Example. Pun intended :-) A relevant beginner example is the highly upvoted Example [Introduction to Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/846/introduction). It has very nice examples with illustrations and explanatory text. It's a very good intro tutorial (really a tutorial more than an example) -- but it's geared towards a beginner learning promises. I haven't looked, but I'll bet there are good tutorials on JS-Promises that are already available. Is this example suitable Docs material?

Comment: @markE: "*Ok, I'll give you an example of a beginner Example.*" We weren't talking about beginner examples; we were talking about beginner *topics*.

Comment: @NicolBolas. Slippery symantics...content is content. Ok, should this Example be stripped out of it's Topic?

Comment: @markE: "*Ok, should this Example be stripped out of it's Topic?*" Why should it be? You seem to think I'm on some anti-beginner crusade or something. What I'm trying to do is find a definition of "topic" that makes topics *useful* towards creating good documentation. And if we have topics that are focused on getting things done, then we make topics reasonably byte-sized, limit the number of viable examples they can have, and make it easier for people to find the information they're looking for, rather than burying it at the bottom of a misc. grab-bag of stuff.

Comment: This is really a very bad use case for docs: Python (and most of its most popular libraries) has notoriously good official documentation, so most of SOD is pointless for that. Whoever is willing to google can already find virtually everything (especially with the crutches of SO main). This also explains why there's an insane amount of plagiarism in this SOD tag.

Answer (score 0):

> What can be done about this?

In general, make the topic smaller. If you define a topic as anything that can be comprehensively treated in not more than 3-12 examples, then topics with a scope greater than this must simply be split. Don't allow different, unrelated parts in an example. Although an example can be somewhat complex, all the parts of an example must relate to each other.

Comment: This doesn't *really* answer the question, IMO, since the topics listed do relate to one another, they're just better suited as footnotes in other topics (probably). I feel like this is a noop answer.

Comment: @ssube If the examples relate to each other than combining them in one example is fine. However OP wrote that they do seem unrelated. If they are unrelated then splitting the topic looks like a good idea. Having footnotes in other topics is fine with me too (it's kind of a splitting). What exactly would you like to have from this answer? A specific proposal what to do for the mentioned topic in the question?

Answer (score 0):

### This is an attempted solution that failed miserably.

Say your car has a broken engine. So you go up to the mechanic (the Stack Overflow dev team) and say "My car has a broken engine. Can you fix that?". After a few minutes of waiting, the mechanic comes back and says "Your car no longer has a broken engine." You thank the mechanic and start the car. But it doesn't start.

You ask the mechanic why the car won't start. S/he says, "because I removed the engine".

I hope you've learned the moral to this "fable". Instead of fixing the actual problem, the dev team just limited the number of examples per topic.

<sub><sup>Really, this should be a comment. But it doesn't fit in a comment and deserves more attention than a comment.</sup></sub>

Comment: I don't think it does. This is speculation and doesn't actually help anyway. Also, it doesn't fit in the comment area because you added a fable for some reason, instead of just saying what you wanted to say (one sentence).

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir a lot of meta posts start with a fable.

Comment: Actually, this fable would be more applicable if the dev team had removed Documentation altogether. And such a move would have been widely celebrated.