# Can we take advantage of large viewports and make columns wider when reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, user-interface, diff

I'm trying to review a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15690240), but I'm struggling to clearly understand what was changed, and one of the reasons is that the two columns are really narrow. The OP's code reaches 120 characters per line, but each column only displays 63 (roughly the half), which means there are horizontal scrollbars. I'm using a Full HD monitor, and it's really a shame that there's so much unused white space on the sides! Would it be possible to check the size of the viewport and, if there's enough space, to make the columns wider, filling all that white space?

[image]

If I switch from "rendered output" to "markdown" view there are no scrollbars, but then the code wraps, which can be even worse. But even in that case there's a lot of unused space.

Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: I should downvote because these aren't hand-drawn red circles ... :/.

Comment: @Tom I know, that's why I added freehand text to compensate for that! :-)

Comment: Easier said then done...Especially when you are reusing this type of design for other pages - I know I know it can be done.

Comment: Related User Experience post: [Why do many sites leave half of each webpage empty?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/why-do-many-sites-leave-half-of-each-webpage-empty)

Comment: To avoid butt-hurt, I would imagine that this could be easily do-able with a toggle-able checkbox such as....`☐ Enable widescreen diffs` and make each diff's width 50% so if you have two monitors then you can just stretch your browser and get a diff on each screen.

Comment: SO's design isn't responsive for small viewports.  Why would you expect it to respond for large viewports?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom SO design = non-responsive = "SO" 2009