# Show related documentation in questions

Tags: feature-request, documentation, questions

Sorry if someone already pointed this, but was not able to find any similar suggestion.

It would be very nice if SO put a list of related documentation of question the same way it's listed related questions at right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this something we'd like to do at some point. Certainly, we could add a link to the sidebar when people link to Documentation topics or examples. In the future, when we have more content, I can easily imagine more proactive links based on tags and keywords.

At the moment, however, we probably don't have enough quality content to make that worthwhile. In turn, we have issues ([reputation balancing, review queue, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331663/1438)) that need to be resolved to make producing that content more enjoyable. There's been plenty of enthusiasm for Documentation from the community, but we haven't harnessed it very well so far. Until we work that part out, we probably don't want to direct more people toward Documentation from Q&A.

At any rate, great suggestion.