# Increase the filtered tags limit in the Documentation review queue.

Tags: feature-request, documentation, review-queues

It would be great to be able to put more than three tags into the “filter” button, so I could review **everything** I’m interested in.

Comment: It would be great to have this in other queues too. (Especially close votes.)

Comment: I could see a DDoS possibility here if you put in 100 tags, but it seems to be fine for search.

Comment: @Laurel I agree, Close Votes should have unlimited votes. Or anything above 1k queue.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Right. If you’re going to spend enough effort to get to 1k, then you’re significantly less likely to try to DoS SO.

Comment: @JF I might not reach 1k, but I don't see a reason why I should DDoS at all.

Comment: Might be good to put in at least some sort-of sensible limit, such as 25..

Comment: @JonasCz Good idea! See edit.

Comment: I prefer this instead [Documentation Update, August 4th](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331751)