# Why limit Documentation to 11 examples?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've checked out the Documentation section a couple of times since it's been released to the public and I honestly cannot see the reason behind limiting **every** topic to 11 examples. I'm sure 11 examples (or less) is fine for certain topics which don't have many use cases however there's certain topics where 11 examples will most likely not cover all of the useful use cases for the topic.

Could we not have a review system where users who monitor / maintain a particular topic can review any new examples and if the example is approved by x amount of reviewers then it'd be added as an example?

Yes there'll be some topics with loads of examples but is that necessarily a bad thing? In these cases the examples should have filters like 'most viewed', 'highest rated', etc.

Comment: Documentation already [goes to 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xgx4k83zzc). What more do you want?

Answer (score 5):

Per [Documentation Update, August 4th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th)

> **Example Limits**
>
> Because some Topics are growing larger than anticipated, we'll be adding soft and hard caps to the number of examples a topic may have. One of the goals of Documentation is to create concise content, and I think it's pretty clear that's not happening in a number of cases.
>
> The soft cap will warn high rep editors after the 6th example, and prevent low rep editors from adding a 7th or greater example. The hard cap will prevent anyone from adding a 13th example. Existing content will be grandfathered in, we're not going to blanket delete anything.
>
> The limits may be tweaked in the future. They're best guesses for "a topic with this many examples is unreasonably large, from the perspective of a consumer or reviewer".

So, it was done to try and make the topics more fine grain so you do not have overly broad topics.  For example, [Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords#t=201704061159332569391) has 64 examples right now.  To me that is a little excessive.

Comment: "little" is an little understatement.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Out of interest what is the criteria for deciding whether or not the topic should have a hard cap?

Comment: @MarkO'Sullivan I believe all topics have a hard cap.  Some have more then the cap because they existed before the cap was put in place.