# Documentation should have pagination

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, documentation

When scrolling through [long documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays), it is annoying how much you have to scroll. Some documentation loads slowly on desktop, and *super slowly* on mobile.

Questions, on the other hand, have pagination:[image]

<sub><sub>You're welcome for the hand-drawn circle.</sub></sub>

Why can't documentation have this?

Comment: There aren't supposed to be that many examples in a topic. It was limited to 11 in the [August Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331663/215552), but older topics were "grandfathered in".

Comment: how could that particular topic possibly fit in 11 examples? how could it even be split up? oh, right, we could remove all the examples that are well covered in the docs (all of them)

Comment: @KevinB: Or you could just remove the topic. "Arrays" is too big to have a topic.

Comment: Building manageable topic hierarchy was at the top of our priority list before the beta was canceled. Thanks for the suggestion.